# LDAP Query returns incorrect results

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to query all users who last logged in more than 30 days ago:

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30).Ticks.ToString();

using (var parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{Environment.UserDomainName}/OU=Company,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM"))
using (var directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(parentEntry))
{
    directorySearch.Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(lastLogonTimestamp<={date})(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
    directorySearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

The query does return a bunch of enabled users, but their `lastLogonTimestamp` values are NOT more than 30 days ago.

For example, here is a sample of some of the dates returned:

```
11/01/2018 8:43:17 PM

14/01/2018 5:14:26 PM

13/01/2018 10:53:58 AM

15/01/2018 9:00:27 AM

15/01/2018 10:36:02 AM

15/01/2018 12:07:02 PM
```

What am I doing wrong?

I can confirm that the `date` value does contain a date 30 days ago (17 December 2017 in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lastLogon` attribute in ActiveDirectory is a 64 bit integer representing dates as the count of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1st, 1601. This definition happens to be the same that WinApi [uses for file times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that this different from the definition of ticks, which start from January 1st, 0001. Thus,

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
var filetime = date.ToFileTime();

/* ... */

directorySearch.Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(lastLogonTimestamp<={filetime}))";
```

Comment: Thanks for that dlatikay - do you know if there is a simple conversion from ticks to whatever that format is called?

Comment: ticks to filetime? that would be `var filetime = new DateTime(ticks).ToFileTime()`. adjusted my answer so it should be less confusing now. we can go from date to filetime directly without the ticks roundtrip